# Embed an image in the body of an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I send emails via Outlook using ".HTMLBody = ..." to customize body.
I tried to add these lines to add an image that I named "logo" in the worksheet:

```
With Sheets("Mail - GREF COMMITTEE AGENDA")
    .Shapes("logo").Export "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\logo.png"
End With

'...

.HTMLBody = bodyEn & bodyFR & "< img src='C:\Users\Public\Pictures\logo.png'>"
```

The error is:

> 438 Object doesn't support this method or property.

**Update**: Any way to embed the image in the mail is helpful. I can export the image manually.

Comment: I don't think there is the export method like there is with the chart.

Comment: So is there another way to do this ? If I save the image manually in my computer, how could I use it in my mail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Word's InlineShapes.AddPicture Method

The procedure is described in [Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx).

Inserting pictures:

```
strFile = "C:\Pictures\logo.gif"
Set objInsp = objMsg.GetInspector
Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection
If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatPlain Then
    objSel.InlineShapes.AddPicture strFile, False, True
End If
```

Comment: Hi Niton. I read the link you gave me. So if I want to embed images in the mail, I have to use Inspector.WordEditor instead of HTMLBody?

Comment: Unless there is a suggested fix of your attempt this is the replacement.